# Exponential random variable

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution

Jones figures that the total number of thousands of miles that an auto can be driven before it would need to be junked is an exponential r.v. with parameter 1/20. Smith has a used car that he claims has been driven only 10,000 miles. If Jones purchases the car, what is the probability that she would get at least 20,000 additional miles out of it? Repeat under the assumption that the lifetime mileage of the car is uniformly distributed over (0,40)?
I did first question as below, is that correct?
Let X denotes the no. of thousands of miles that an auto can be driven
    P(X>30) = 1 – F(30)
           = 1 – (1 -  e-µx)
       = e-µx
       = e –(1/20)(30)
                  = 0.223

but i have no idea for the 2nd question, any hints?

Comment: The answer to the first question is wrong, you need $\Pr(X\ge 30|X\ge 10)$. So you need to divide your answer by $\Pr(X\ge 10)$. This will be exactly the same as the plain $\Pr(X\ge 20)$. We could have bypassed most of the calculation, and gotten the right answer, by invoking the **memorylessness** of the exponential. Important note: The exponential model is a lousy model for the lifetime of cars.

Answer (score 1):

For the uniform, we want
$$\Pr(X\ge 30|X\ge 10).$$
By the definition of conditional probability, this is
$$\frac{\Pr(X\ge 30\cap X\ge 10)}{\Pr(X\ge 10}.$$
Now calculate. We get 
$$\frac{10/40}{30/40}.$$

The exponential distribution case was dealt with in a comment. By the **memorylessness** of the exponential, we have
$$\Pr(X\ge 30|X\ge 10)=\Pr(X\ge 20)=\int_{20}^\infty \frac{1}{20}e^{-t/20}\,dt=e^{-20/20}.$$

Alternately, we can do a conditional probability calculation as in the uniform case. We we do that, we will get $\frac{e^{-30/20}}{e^{-10/20}}$, which is the same as the number we got using memorylessness.

Comment: Thanks, for question B, is that corrct?                       P (X>30) = 1 – P(X<30)
= 1- (30)(1/40)
= 0.25

Comment: That is the $10/40$ of my answer above. It is correct. I thought of it directly instead of by subtraction. We want the probability of ending up in the interval $[30,40]$. Because we are dealing with a uniform distribution, that's the length of the interval, which is $10$, divided by the length of the interval $[0,40]$.